# Cross-Platform mobile app development tool to connect to remote mysql database

Tags: android, ios, cross-platform, mysql, jdbc

I am working on a native PHP website with a very bad architecture and with no web services to use. The owner needs a mobile app to communicate with his website and fetch some data from the database.

I started working with android studio with JDBC but It's really broken and didn't really work and It will probably be harder for IOS app to establish this connection. So, **I was wondering if there is other Cross-Platform mobile tools which provide remote db connection.**

I know that It's really bad to connect directly to a database rather than using web services, it's just a temporary solution but a must to do ASAP.

Please help,
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [build .Net Standard Xamarin Forms application](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/) and use [Xamarin.MySql.Data](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.MySql.Data/) library for connecting to MariaDB/MySQL database or [System.Data.SqlClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SqlClient/) library for Sql database.

Comment: Hi @Nicole if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.